# Select all checkbox issue

Tags: jquery

In HTML, when I click on checkbox from the list it adds class to its parent li, but when I need to select all checkbox when any one of the lists is already selected then it mismatches.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row lml-dashboard">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 left-section">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                                <div class="panel-heading"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"> 
                                    <select class="select-admin">
                                        <option>7 Operators</option>
                                        <option>7 Trainers</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <!-- List group -->
                                <ul class="list-group member-list">
                                    <li class="list-group-item checked">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]" checked="checked"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Kimberly Palmer
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Christopher Henry
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Henry Edwards
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Dylan Gordon
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Aaron Ford
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Benjamin Allen
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="checkbox-lms" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> 
                                            <span class="avatar"><img src="images/user.png"></span>
                                            Henry Sanchez
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".member-list li :checkbox").on('click', function(){
        $(this).parents(".list-group-item").toggleClass("checked");
    });
    $("#select_all").on('click', function(){
        $(".list-group-item").toggleClass("checked",this.checked);
    });
```

**Demo:**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/regrduq5/

Comment: all add relevant code in OP itself. if you want to show a demo use `<>`

Comment: your link has no code in it. share the relevant code.

Comment: Added fiddle link

Comment: @Appy no - please put the code in the question. If jsFiddle goes down (as it occasionally does) then your question will be unanswerable.

Comment: Don't use toggleClass - add/remove the class specifically (or use the parameterised version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select all checkbox checked state while toggling the class checked in list groups:

```
$("#select_all").on('click', function(){
  $(".list-group-item").toggleClass("checked",this.checked);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lhksuxcz/)**

Comment: That's great, thanx, you made my day